# O365 cant import Mailbox

Tags: python, office365

I am testing O365 for a project that I have to download some attachments for.  I am just attempting to connect to the server and get a feel for how to use this module.  I am not even able to get the import to work correctly.  I have followed some tutorials online as well as looked at the documentation and there is Mailbox option, so im not sure what the issue is.  Any suggestions?

> ```
> (project2) User1@User1-MacBook-Pro project2 % python3 main.py
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/Users/User1/Documents/scripts/Python/project2/main.py", line 2, in <module>
>     from O365 import Account, Message, MailBox
> ImportError: cannot import name 'MailBox' from 'O365' (/Users/User1/Documents/scripts/Python/project2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/O365/__init__.py)
> (project2) User1@User1-MacBook-Pro project2 % pip3 show o365
> Name: O365
> Version: 2.0.16
> Summary: Microsoft Graph and Office 365 API made easy
> Home-page: https://github.com/O365/python-o365
> Author: Janscas, Roycem90, Narcolapser
> Author-email: janscas@users.noreply.github.com
> License: Apache License 2.0
> Location: /Users/User1/Documents/scripts/Python/project2/lib/python3.9/site-packages
> Requires: pytz, tzlocal, requests-oauthlib, stringcase, beautifulsoup4, requests, python-dateutil
> Required-by:
> ```

```
from O365 import Account, Message, MailBox

scopes=['basic', 'message_all']
credentials=('extra_secure_password', 'user@somedomain.com')
account = Account(credentials = credentials)

# if not account.is_authenticated:  # will check if there is a token and has not expired
#     account.authenticate(scopes=scopes)

# account.connection.refresh_token().mailbox = account.mailbox()
inbox = mailbox.get_folder(folder_name='Inbox')
child_folders = inbox.get_folders(25)
for folder in child_folders:
    print(folder.name, folder.parent_id)
```

Comment: `Mailbox` or `MailBox`? What's in the file? What makes you think your code is correct? Please also create a [mcve] to include in your question, which would boil down to a single line in this case. Oh, also search for the error message, you'll find hundreds of similar ones that should explain the general problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey maybe you must follow this way

```
from O365 import Connection, MSGraphProtocol
from O365.message import Message
from O365.mailbox import MailBox

protocol = MSGraphProtocol()
scopes = ['...']
con = Connection(('client_id', 'client_secret'), scopes=scopes)

message = Message(con=con, protocol=protocol)
# ...
mailbox = MailBox(con=con, protocol=protocol)
message2 = Message(parent=mailbox)  # message will inherit the connection and protocol from mailbox when using parent.
# ...
```

Your error is in this line :

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'MailBox' from 'O365'
```

and you must write that:

```
from O365.mailbox import MailBox
```

for find full article go to this page - https://github.com/O365/python-o365#mailbox